# Pandas astype() extremely slow with large number of nulls?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a dataframe of decent size (95,000 rows, 68 columns.) When I load in the excel file it makes a certain column go from text to being interpreted as an int. I either need a way to specify on loading that a certain column is to hold strings, or I need to figure out why astype(str) is performing so slowly.

Example code below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
    'C': ['1.1', '2.1', '3.0', '4.1', '5.1'] })
df['A']=df['A'].astype(str)+'addedtext'
print(df)
```

This code works fine, does exactly what I want, changing Column A from ints to strings and verifying they are strings by using + with other strings and getting the result I want

The problem is, running this on a single column (95000 rows) of my other dataframe takes 7-8 minutes.  I feel like thats very slow for such a simple change?  Maybe I'm crazy.  Is there a faster method?  Is there a way to load a csv or excel file in but specify one column by a certain data type before hand?  Could it have to do with the fact that there is a very large number of nulls in that column?

EDIT: Im just dumb.  my timing loop contained the saving of the file.

Comment: _The problem is, running this on a single column (95000 rows) of my other dataframe takes 7-8 minutes._ That seems insane, can you benchmark/profile the program? _Is there a way to load a csv or excel file in but specify one column by a certain data type before hand?_ I'm not sure about Excel files, but I know that it's certainly possible when reading CSV files. How are the null values represented? How are you currently reading the input?

Comment: The null cells in excel have no data in them. Im reading the input from a .xlsx file using pandas.read_excel()
Using both astype() and list comprehension as suggested below both took 452 seconds to perform the data conversion

Comment: Can you share how you're calling the function?

Comment: What do you mean? It shouldn't take that long just to write the file, no?

Comment: Then what's taking that much time? You said 7-8 minutes in total, right?

Comment: In my experience, no, it shouldnt take 452 seconds to write 67MB.  However, I am not writing locally, although the server is in-house and we have MASSIVE bandwidth, such that transferring the file from its write location back to a local location is sub 2 seconds, also im consolidating some replies to shorten the reply chain

Comment: Replies? Would you like to share more of the program, so we can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe try a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
    'C': ['1.1', '2.1', '3.0', '4.1', '5.1'] })

start= time.time()
df['A']=df['A'].astype(str)+'addedtext'
end = time.time()
print('original:', end-start)

start= time.time()
df['A']=[str(x) + 'addedtext' for x in df['A']]
end = time.time()
print('slightly faster alternative', end-start)
```

my results were:

original: 0.002001523971557617

slightly faster alternative 0.000997781753540039

Hope this helps

Comment: I made a timing error on my part, and was including the write time.  But just for future pondering, on my end, the process takes essentially the same time (within 2% of each other) when using list comprehension vs using astype() on my file